# Android - NullPointerException on setAdapter ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have a little problem. I'm trying to create a layout with fragment, but when I call the `setAdapter` method I have a Java `NullPointerException`, and I can't find the error.
Thanks all!

**Class Code**

```
public class Agenda extends FragmentActivity{

PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.agenda_sw);

    mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.agendaPager);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter); //Line 32, the error is on this line.

}
```

**xml code**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/agenda_sw"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
/>
```

**LogCat**

```
03-04 11:06:14.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 11:06:14.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{conf.main/conf.main.Agenda}: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
03-04 11:06:14.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 11:06:14.686: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): at conf.main.Agenda.onCreate(Agenda.java:32)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrong viewpager id. You wrote in xml:

```
android:id="@+id/agenda_sw"
```

But in code you find for R.id.agendaPager and should for R.id.agenda_sw.

Comment: It was in my intention but i had to wait some minutes before do it